# Value of type 'MySqlConnection' cannot be converted to 'String'

Tags: vb.net, mysql-connector

When i try to running my code, it appear
Value of type 'MySqlConnection' cannot be converted to 'String'.

My code is shown below.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Module ConnectionDatabase
    Public Function strconnection() As MySqlConnection
        Return New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=value power meter")
    End Function

    Public strcon As MySqlConnection = strconnection()

    Public result As String
    Public cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Public da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Public dt As New DataTable

    Public Sub create(ByVal sql As String)
        Try
            strcon.Open()
            With cmd
                .Connection = strcon
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub reload(ByVal sql As String, ByVal DTG As Object)
        Try
            dt = New DataTable
            strcon.Open()
            With cmd
                .Connection = strcon
                .CommandText = sql
            End With
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
            DTG.datasource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            strcon.Close()
            da.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub updates(ByVal sql As String)
        Try
            strcon.Open()
            With cmd
                .CommandText = strcon
                .CommandText = sql

                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            strcon.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub delete(ByVal sql As String)
        Try
            strcon.Open()
            With cmd
                .CommandText = strcon
                .CommandText = sql

                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            strcon.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code:

```
.CommandText = strcon
.CommandText = sql
```

Change to

```
.Connection = strcon
.CommandText = sql
```

Complete correction

```
Public Sub updates(ByVal sql As String)
    Try
        strcon.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = strcon
            .CommandText = sql

            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        strcon.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub delete(ByVal sql As String)
    Try
        strcon.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = strcon
            .CommandText = sql

            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        strcon.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```